# Do Original Trilogy TIE Fighters now have Life support?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

The Question is do Original Trilogy TIE Fighter's now have life support?

In Star Wars Rebels S3:E4, A TIE Interceptor Pilot is chasing a TIE Bomber and Corellian Corvette and the Corvette jumps to hyperspace.

The pilot's suit/helmet was the life support system for the TIE Pilot.

The pilots in the TIE Bomber are not wearing their helmets. It is unclear whether they left the atmosphere or lower atmosphere. However, their intention was to get into space to escape.

Furthermore, when the Corvette escapes, the TIE interceptor pilot removes his helmet when he was within a few meters of where the Corvette had previously been. Seeing as the Corvette made the jump, can we infer that the Corvette was outside of the atmosphere or at least well beyond the lower atmosphere where life support would still be necessary?

Comment: TIE fighters of the First Order seemed to have life support, as we saw Poe and Finn fly one without any helmets or masks in *The Force Awakens*.

Comment: @Essen it's still possible that the fighter lacked life support but was *sealed to the vacuum of space*. Poe and Finn's relatively short flight to the surface might have been done with whatever air was lingering inside the cockpit. It's not clear if TIE fighters are normally flown with a vacuum inside the cockpit, or whether their cockpits are sealed like most ships but simply lack the supplies or equipment to refresh the air inside.

Comment: @Essen  Friendly point of clarification. The question was whether *original* trilogy TIE fighters have life support, not whether the TIE fighters in the sequel trilogy have life support. Also, the question mentioned characters and events from before the original trilogy, but did not mention any events from the sequel trilogy. Granted that the First Order could simply build more TIE fighters with the same specs that the Empire used a generation earlier, but they could also add life support and other features if they chose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Star Wars Rebels Visual Guide indicates that TIE Fighters ***lack*** life support

> "...TIE fighters lack deflector shields, life support, ejection systems
>   and hyperdrives."

[image]

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Star-Wars-Rebels-Visual-Guide/dp/1409353303

Comment: I guess that is a cannon source for an answer, So was the helmet-less pilot just an inconsistency?

Comment: not necessarily - we've seen in Rogue One that you can jump to hyperspace in atmosphere

Comment: NKCampbell That is true I forgot Rogue also...changed...on of my more favorite aspects of hyperspace travel. However, I still maintain that at High Altitude, some form of life support systems would have been needed. Furthermore, the ships were far enough out of the planet that the "sky" was a black star-field. +1 for the Rogue One reference, Was that on Jeddha (spelling?) that they jumped in the atmosphere?

Comment: yup - that was Jedha